# {R} Remove blank or unique columns using purrr

Tags: r, variables, dictionary, unique, purrr

I recently discovered purrr and I really like the map function. Does anyone know how to tackle the following problem:

I have a dataframe that I split into multiple dataframes based on a certain variable - once split I would like to remove the columns in the dataframes in the resulting list that are unique. Solving this in a single dataframe is quite easy, but in a list I am not too sure - how would you solve this by using map?

My current solution is as follow:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(target    = round(runif(9, min = 0, max = 1), 0),
                  split_var = c(rep("x", 3), rep("y", 3), rep("z", 3)),
                  var1      = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 2), "c", rep("d", 2), "e"),
                  var2      = paste("m", round(rnorm(9, mean = 5), 2), sep = "_"))

mod_dat <- dat %>% split(dat$split_var) 
remover <- function(df){
  non_unique_cols <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1
  return(df[, non_unique_cols])
}
map(mod_dat, remover)
```

There is an additional problem, I don't want `map` to apply `remover` to the `target` variable.
Can anyone please help doing this using map from the purrr package.

SOLVED

The final solution as provided by @akrun - full credit goes to him.

```
mod_dat <- dat %>% 
  split(.$split_var) %>% 
  map( ~ Filter(function(x) n_distinct(x) > 1, .)) %>% 
  Filter(function(x) sum(names(x) %in% "target"), .)
mod_dat
```

The slight difference is that here we also drop dataframes which drop the target variable - for my purposes it is not nessecary to keep these dataframes. The following code can be used to quickly determine which levels are kept, and which are removed.

```
# In
unique(dat$split_var)[(unique(dat$split_var) %in% names(mod_dat))]
# Out
unique(dat$split_var)[!(unique(dat$split_var) %in% names(mod_dat))]
```

Comment: @akrun I am adding it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>% 
   split(.$split_var) %>%
   map(~Filter(function(x) n_distinct(x) >1 , .))
```

---

Based on the OP's dataset and the updated question, we can use `setdiff` to select only columns that are required to `Filter`, and with `bind_cols`, we can join the 'target'

```
 dat %>% 
     split(.$split_var) %>% 
     map(~bind_cols(.["target"], Filter(function(x) 
        n_distinct(x) >1 , .[setdiff(names(.), "target")])))
#$x
#  target   var2
#1      0 m_4.89
#2      1 m_4.88
#3      0 m_5.18

#$y
#  target var1   var2
#1      1    b m_6.28
#2      1    b m_3.27
#3      0    c m_6.69

#$z
#  target var1   var2
#1      1    d  m_5.5
#2      1    d m_7.53
#3      1    e m_5.55
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep(1, 3), 4:10), split_var = rep(LETTERS[1:3],
            c(3, 3, 4)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Beautiful! That is so much better! It does exactly what I have. There is a slight problem, how can I specify to not apply it to the target variable?

Comment: @CharlFrancoisMarais  What is the target variable?

Comment: I added it in my original post - please have a look. It should be either **1** or **0**

Comment: @CharlFrancoisMarais  Do you want `dat %>% split(.$split_var) %>% map(~Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) >1 , .[setdiff(names(.), "target")]))`

Comment: Not exactly, I would like to keep the target variable in each dataframe, what your code is doing is removing it in each. The best way for me to explain is that I want the function to be applied on the entire dataframe, except for variable `target`

Comment: @CharlFrancoisMarais  In that case `dat %>% split(.$split_var) %>% map(~bind_cols(.["target"], Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) >1 , .[setdiff(names(.), "target")])))`

Comment: Perfect! You really helped a ton! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CharlFrancoisMarais  If you need the `dplyr` syntax, `length(unique(x))` can be changed to `n_distinct(x)`

Comment: Looking at it now, those dataframe should actually be removed - but no worries this I can handle!

Comment: yes you are right, that is even more sleek! Thanks again!

Comment: @CharlFrancoisMarais  If you want those data.frames removed `dat %>% split(.$split_var) %>% map(~Filter(function(x) n_distinct(x) > 1, .)) %>% Filter(function(x) ncol(x)==(ncol(dat)-1), .)`

Comment: Hmmm, no, not exactly, maybe you misunderstood me - you are removing all dataframes where one column is removed. This is not what I meant, I only need to remove the dataframes where the varaible `target` was removed.

Comment: But the question is answered - the rest is simple ;) I need to remove the dataframes where target is unique since no model can be built on these dataframes...

Comment: @CharlFrancoisMarais  Okay, thanks, if you can solve it from your end, no problem